# Aframe: Physics + Animation

Tags: aframe, cannon.js

I find when I apply Don Mccurdy's `physics` system to a body by setting it as a `dynamic-body`, any animations using Ngokevin's `animation` component does not seem to get activated? For e.g something like this does not call the animation

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive:sphere;" material="color:red" dynamic-body
  animation="property:rotation; to:0 360 0; loop:true"></a-entitiy>
```

Any work around on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use them both at once as they collide and do the same thing (move the entity). Disable / pause dynamic-body component (e.g., `el.components['dynamic-body'].pause()` might work
 or `removeAttribute('dynamic-body')`) before starting animation.